# Count how many of each character appears in C

Tags: c, list

I'm trying to do exercise 1-14 from the C programming language book by Brian Kernighan.

I'm using a list a list where the index number corresponds to the ASCII value, so list[65] should print out the number of times 'A' has appeared in my input.

Unfortunately my program just seems not to increment. Any help would be appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLEN 1000

int main()
{
    int c, i;
    int chartype[MAXLEN];

    for(i = 0; i < MAXLEN; ++i)
        chartype[i] = 0;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        ++chartype[c - '0'];
    }


    for(i = 0; i < MAXLEN; ++i){
        if(chartype[i]>0)
            printf("%c, %d\n", i, chartype[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output: 53, ? 56, ?

Comment: `c - '0'` - whoever told you that was the index to use lied.  you should use simply `c`. Your current index makes the statement *"...where the index number corresponds to the ASCII value..."* untrue.

Comment: Why is `MAXLEN` set to 1000?  Why are you subtracting `'0'` from `c`?

Comment: What makes you conclude it isn't incrementing, rather than incrementing the wrong thing(s)?  What *should* the output be?

Comment: Your just setting chartype[1000]=0 in for loop. Instead just initialize with {0} or {""}.  Your code is not incrementing. What are you doing here c-'0' ? What's your intention?

Comment: "*Count how many of each character appears in C*" One? ;-)

Comment: You should be able to use CHAR_MIN and CHAR_MAX to come up with an appropriate range for the array. Be careful to index it considering that `char` might be negative. You shouldn't need to depend on `char` being an ASCII codepoint—it hardly ever is. (Of course, you can require it to be for your program but I'm just saying that's not common or what users expect.)

Comment: The c-'0' was a misguided, this is commonly used to make a character digit into an int. The reason I think it's not incrementing is because if I enter 5 unique characters, it prints only a seemingly random one of those.

Comment: @TomBlodget With `while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        ++chartype[c - '0'];
    }`, `c` is not negative inside the loop.  `getchar()` returns a value in the range of `unsigned char` and `EOF`.  Using `UCHAR_MAX+1` for the array size makes more sense.  Note that there is no `char` in the OP's code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that `c - '0'` in the second loop.

When you type 'A', you're incrementing the integer in index position c - '0', which is c - 48. So for 'A', it's incrementing integer number 17 (65-48), which is some special character.

By just typing `++chartype[c]`, you increment the position of the character in the array and fix the problem.

Also getchar() will take the input when you press the Enter key on input console or on encountering end of line in the input file. It will increment the value at index 10 every time Enter key is pressed or end of line is encountered. So simply add a condition in the last loop to avoid printing that. Or you can refer to some other sources to check how getchar() can avoid enter key or end of line.

I have also used the suggestions given by Phil Kiener.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c, i;
    int chartype[256] = { 0 }; // maximum value for an unsigned char

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        ++chartype[c]; // no need to subtract '0'
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 255; ++i) {
        if(chartype[i] > 0 && i!='\n') { //avoiding printing value present at index 10
            printf("%c, %d\n", i, chartype[i]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `&& i!= '\n'` would be more self-explanatory and more portable than `&& i!=10`

Comment: Is int chartype[256] = { 0 }; a simpler version of int chartype[256] = { 0 };`? And thank you for the response!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `c - '0'` inside the square brackets.

When you type 'A', it should increment the integer with index 65, so that when you print the character with the value 65 it gives you 'A'.

Instead, you're incrementing the integer in index position `c - '0'`, which is `c - 48`. Here, when you type 'A', it's incrementing integer number 17 (65 - 48), which is some special character.

By putting just `++chartype[c];`, you increment the correct position in the array and fix the problem.

Two asides:

- `c - '0'` is only used when your input is a string of digits, and you want to count the number of times '0' in the 0-th position of the array, etc.
- You don't need to allocate such a big array for simple chars. There are 256 possible values for `c`, so a `MAXLEN` of 256 should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You probably got something mixed up in your code.

```
int chartype[MAXLEN];
```

You want to store how often a character appears in an array, where each index corresponds to a character. But there are not 1000 characters, only 256.

```
++chartype[c - '0'];
```

The "idiom" `c - '0'` is often used to quickly get a numeric value from a digit (`'9'` becomes `9`); you don't want to do this here.

To actually count how often the characters appear, do as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c, i;
    int chartype[256] = { 0 }; // maximum value for an unsigned char

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        ++chartype[c]; // no need to subtract '0'
    }


    for(i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
        if(chartype[i] > 0) {
            printf("%c, %d\n", i, chartype[i]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`getchar()` returns an `unsigned char`, casted to an `int` to accomodate for `EOF`, so an array of length 256 is enough to capture all characters.

`int chartype[256] = { 0 };` initializes all values in that array to `0`, so you don't need that first loop.

(Also, `chartype` is a poor name. `char_frequency` or something the like would be better in terms of readability.)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, problem with not only your code but other's here is that it only return to be a list of characters, certain numbers,  and spaces, not letters. Is this a compiler issue? I'm using mingw on Windows

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is your index. You could be having lower case letters, upper case letters and digits (ignoring symbols I assume). Since upper case letters start at 65 in ascii, digits at 48 and lower case letters at 97, I would suggest three tables for counting each and utilizing isupper and isdigit methods provided by string.h. if this is a university exercise where string.h is forbidden then I would suggest the following pseudocode

```
If character larger or equal to a
Remove 97, increment position in lowercase letters array
Else if larger or equal to A
Remove 65, increment position in uppercase letters array
Else
Remove 48, increment position in digits array
```

Answer (score 0):

`++chartype[c - '0'];` can easily write below the bound of [0...MAXLEN).

Example `' ' - '0'` may be 32 - 48 or -16.  Better to offset based on zero.

1. Make `chartype[];` big enough to use any `unsigned char` as an index.  There are `UCHAR_MAX + 1` possible `unsigned char`.  `fgetc()` returns a value in the range of `unsigned char` or `EOF`.

   ```
   #include <limits.h>
   ... 
   // int chartype[MAXLEN]; // not right sized
   int chartype[UCHAR_MAX + 1];
   ```
2. Easy enough to *initialize*  `chartype[]` elements to zero.

   ```
   int chartype[UCHAR_MAX + 1] = {0};
   ```
3. Increment and print based on a zero offset, not the *character* `'0'`.

   ```
   while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
     // chartype[c - '0']
     ++chartype[c];
   }

   for (int i = 0; i <= UCHAR_MAX; i++) {
     if(chartype[i]>0) {
       printf("%c, %d\n", i, chartype[i]);
     } 
   }
   ```

Note: Different code needed for rare platforms where the range of `unsigned char` meets/exceeds the range of `int`.